# Docker is giving me an error when running it

Tags: docker

I'm using windows and installed docker recently. I've just run command

```
docker run busybox
```

and it gives

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (windows/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
```

After this I ran
 `docker run busybox --platform windows/amd64` and still gives me same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker options need to go before the image name, so you should use

```
docker run --platform windows/amd64 busybox
```